# Logcat Error at AllProductsActivity.java

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, logcat

Null pointer exception at runtime.I am getting an Exception at these lines

Below I am posted the Logcat and codes related to that.

**Stacktrace:**

```
10-20 07:13:32.092: E/Buffer Error(2936): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
    10-20 07:13:32.092: E/JSON Parser(2936): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
    10-20 07:13:32.152: W/dalvikvm(2936): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a7eba8)
    10-20 07:13:32.162: E/AndroidRuntime(2936): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    10-20 07:13:32.162: E/AndroidRuntime(2936): Process: com.example.androidhive, PID: 2936
    10-20 07:13:32.162: E/AndroidRuntime(2936): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    10-20 07:13:32.162: E/AndroidRuntime(2936):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)

    10-20 07:13:32.162: E/AndroidRuntime(2936):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    10-20 07:13:32.162: E/AndroidRuntime(2936):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    10-20 07:13:32.162: E/AndroidRuntime(2936):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    10-20 07:13:32.162: E/AndroidRuntime(2936): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    10-20 07:13:32.162: E/AndroidRuntime(2936):     at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:130)
    10-20 07:13:32.162: E/AndroidRuntime(2936):     at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
    10-20 07:13:32.162: E/AndroidRuntime(2936):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    10-20 07:13:32.162: E/AndroidRuntime(2936):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    10-20 07:13:32.162: E/AndroidRuntime(2936):     ... 3 more
    10-20 07:13:32.752: I/Choreographer(2936): Skipped 120 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    10-20 07:13:33.462: I/Choreographer(2936): Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b3d35370 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-461,175} that was originally added here
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:348)
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936):  at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(AllProductsActivity.java:117)
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936):  at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity.onCreate(AllProductsActivity.java:57)
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    10-20 07:13:34.722: E/WindowManager(2936):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**AllProductsActivity.java:**

```
 package com.example.androidhive;  

public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://localhost/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();  ---->57th line

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        EditProductActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received 
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();   ---->117th line
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products:", json.toString()); ---->130th line

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

**JsonParser.java:**

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidhive"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

     <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

     <!--  Internet Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >


        <activity
            android:name=".MainScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- All Product Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity"
            android:label="All Products" >
        </activity>

        <!-- Add Product Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".NewProductActivity"
            android:label="Add New Product" >
        </activity>

        <!-- Edit Product Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".EditProductActivity"
            android:label="Edit Product" >
        </activity>  
    </application>



</manifest>
```

Anybody can help me with this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: call `finish()` after `startActivity()` method and why `return null` in `doInBackground()` ?

Comment: String type so I need to return null. @Rustam

Comment: if you don't want to return anything better change the return type to `void`.

Comment: @Rustam then I get compile error like this `The return type is incompatible with AsyncTask<String,String,String>.doInBackground(String[])`

Comment: try this may be it will help Log.d("All Products ", "> " + json);

Comment: you can change to `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>` and `doInBackground(Void ...args)`

Comment: make sure your `json` in `doInBackground(...)` is not `null`

Comment: now I am getting error at this line `int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);` @AdityaVyas

Comment: @Rustam Now I changed it as Void.Now return is null

Comment: try this two lines in your try block hope it will work   products=new JSONArray(json);
if(products != null)

Comment: then what's problem?

Comment: Still the same error posted in logcat @Rustam

Comment: @steve did you solve this problem because i am getting same error now?

Comment: yeah but i am using live server data..no localhost there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your `ip address` instead of local host.I solved this error with the help of using my ip address instead of using loc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check out this answer: 
[Json object integrate with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876704/json-object-integrate-with-android/28971504#28971504)

Also make sure that inside your android code, you changed the private static URL variables inside AllProductsActivity.java, EditProductActivity.java, and NewProductActivity.java to your IP Address. For example, for AllProductsActivity.java it should be:

[image: Java fields]